# How to target subdirectories in BuckleScript bsconfig.json

Tags: reason, bucklescript

I have the following folder structure

```
--| button
--|--| button.re
main.re
```

In my `bsconfig.json`, using the quickstart guide found [here](https://reasonml.github.io/guide/javascript/quickstart). I have in my config the following key/value:

```
"sources": [
  "src/"
]
```

It is only targeting the main.re file. I have tried some conventional config options such as `*.re`, but to no avail. If I would like to target all sub-directories, how would I do so? Thank you.

Comment: One way to circumvent the problem is to not have nested directories at all, and instead put all your source files in a single directory, with names like `ui_Button.re`. You'll then also need a 'table of contents' module for each level of the hierarchy to set up the nested module structure using module aliases, e.g. in `ui.re`: `module Button = Ui_Button`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was actually a PR merged just yesterday that adds support for directory traversal. It'll be in the next release, which should be out shortly.

The configuration will then be:

```
"sources": [{"dir": "src", "subdirs": true}]
```

Edit: [This feature was released in 1.9.2](https://github.com/BuckleScript/bucklescript/blob/master/Changes.md#192)

Comment: I will say I am running across some errors using the above, and will try to be vocal in github repo.

Comment: Happy to help! You're more than welcome to hop on to the [Reason Discord](https://discord.gg/reasonml) to ask for help too. The author of BuckleScript hangs around there as well.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at documentation the solution would be the following:

```
"sources": [{"dir": "src", "subdirs": ["button"]}],
```

Source for documentation: https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/docson/#build-schema.json